Blazor Injection of a helper class to other classes
this is using Blazor c#/html.
im taking a helper class:
    public class HelperClass
    {
        public bool HelperClassBoolF { get; set; }
        public bool HelperClassBoolT { get; set; }

        public HelperClass()
        {
            HelperClassBoolF = false;
            HelperClassBoolT = true;
        }

    }

and wanting to set the variable in PrintShopAttachment.cs, then have it use it in Attachment.cs
in startup.cs i am using
services.AddSingleton<HelperClass>();

classes do not allow injection, the @sign doesn't allow any sort of auto fill. how can classes share a global variables. i was wanting the helper class usable in both PrintShopAttachment.cs and Attachment.cs.

What classes does not allow injection? What is @sign? What is PiontShopAttachement.cs? Is it a razor component?

@Liero - All classes i cannot use injection the same. normally i can just do something like "@inject HelperClass HC", then use HC.HelperClassBoolF as a variable.
Both .CS is a class component.

Just use standard constructor injection. In your classes add a constructor that takes a parameter HelperClass helperClass.

Are you trying to inject into standard classes or into component classes?  Can you show an example of how you are trying to inject HelperClass and from where?

You could try [Inject] property in your class component
[Inject]
HelperClass HelperClass { get; set; }


This only works for component classes.
